# editing pure data on aggrid?

Tags: ag-grid, ngrx

I have an observable that is used on the grid data, which is read only and comes from ngrx.

I need to enable edit to some cells. But anytime I try to edit a cell I get the following:

```
//cannot add property prop, object is not extensible
```

getRowNodeId is working but I still get this error. Tried to find an example but got nothing.

Any place a can find how editing from a immutable data source supposed to work with ag-grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using [ValueSetters](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-setters/#value-setter).

Basically you use value setter to trigger the state change from the store instead of leaving it to ag-grid and the cell editing works correctly.

good example [here](https://blog.ag-grid.com/building-crud-in-ag-grid-with-angular-ngrx/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the "cellValueChanged" property on the column definition.

Pass it a function that will accept a CellValueChangedEvent that gives you the old value, the new value, and access to the row data.

Then it's up to you as far as how to "edit" your immutable data.
Generally speaking, you don't modify your immutable data (that's why it's immutable) - you produce new immutable data.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a **immutable** data, you don't want to edit the data.

I'd suggest to create a deep copy of the data and pass the copied data to Ag-grid table. So basically you are making a **mutable** data here.

Then now you are ready to edit your data